# Typescript | Decorator doesn't seem to be registering properly

Tags: angular, typescript, decorator

I have a problem currently when working with Typescript decorators within Angular.

I am trying to make a simple decorator which you can specify what type of input a control is or select options etc, the idea behind it is I am able to build a form just from a model.

```
export class UserForm {
    @Input('text')
    @Required()
    firstName: string;

    @Input('text')
    @Required()
    lastName: string;
}
```

The required decorator works perfectly and I have absolutely no issues with it but for whatever reason the @Input() directive deosn't seem to work. (I know the name clashes with Angulars Input but I am 100% ensuring I am using the correct one). Currently I have a very basic decorator...

```
export const Input = (inputType: string) => {
    return (): PropertyDecorator => {
        return (target: object, propertyKey: string) => {
            console.log(inputType, target, propertyKey);
        };
    };
};
```

whenever I do this I get the following error

> 'Input('text')' accepts too few arguments to be used as a decorator here. Did you mean to call it first and write '@Input('text')()'?

I literally have no idea why this is happening, I have tried putting in a function at the top of the file and not exporting.

Also worth mentioning this is done within a Angular library setup and I did read somewhere that it's to do with the typings, but I wasn't too sure because required works.